# How can I access to a subfolder of htdocs directory of XAMPP?

Tags: php, xampp, localhost, htdocs

When I use header() to redirect the user to another folder of my htdocs directory:

[image]

the browser shows this error.

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

```
elseif (preg_match('/^[آ ا ب پ ت ث ج چ ح خ د ذ ر ز ژ س ش ص ض ط ظ ع غ ف ق ک گ ل م ن و ه ی]/', $name) === 0){
    header('Location: http://localhost/error/error1.php'); /* Redirect browser */
    // /^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\/[0-9][0-9]\/[0-9][0-9]$/
    $check_error = 1;
}
```